# Prevent recalculation of random numbers between frames

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, random-numbers

In a beamer presentation, I am generating a schematic that involves some randomness by using rand to calculate coordinates. Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
          \draw[fill=blue!20] (-3,0) rectangle (3,-0.2);

          \draw[red, thick,-latex] (0,2) -- (0,0);
     
          \draw[fill=red,red,thick, -latex] (0,0)
          \foreach \i in {1,...,10} {
            -- ++(rand*0.3+0.3,rand*0.3-0.3) circle(0.05)
          };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The issue is that this snippet needs to be within an `\only<1->{}` block. I need the randomness to be used to construct the schematic once, and then show an unchanged schematic on subsequent frames. However, as you might expect, the schematic changes as rand is recalculated. Is there an option to `\begin{tikzpicture}` that freezes the schematic after the first frame?

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.